# Pam_unix sshd authentication failure even though the login works?

Tags: linux, sshd, pam, winbind

I have a server that is configured with winbind and samba to provide active directory authentication. The active directory integration works fine however whenever I authenticate I see the following errors:

### **Errors**

Authentication:

```
May 11 00:25:29 SERVER sshd[28119]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=x.x.x.x  user=USERNAME
```

Sudo:

```
May 11 01:33:14 SERVER sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=USER_NAME uid=2005125 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/2 ruser=USER_NAME rhost=  user=USER_NAME
```

### **Configuration**

/etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
[global]
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        realm = DOMAIN NAME
        security = ADS
        winbind enum users = Yes
        winbind enum groups = Yes
        winbind use default domain = No
        winbind separator = +
        kerberos method = secrets and keytab
        idmap config * : backend = autorid
        idmap config * : range = 1000000-19999999
        idmap config * : rangesize = 1000000
        template shell = /bin/bash
        netbios name = SERVERNAME
```

/etc/pam.d/system-auth

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_winbind.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_winbind.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_winbind.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     optional      pam_mkhomedir.so umask=0077
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_winbind.so
```

/etc/pam.d/sshd

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required     pam_sepermit.so
auth       substack     password-auth
auth       include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-auth      optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
password   include      password-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
session    include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-session   optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
```

sshd_config:

```
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem sftp  /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
AuthorizedKeysCommand /opt/aws/bin/eic_run_authorized_keys %u %f
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser ec2-instance-connect
Banner /etc/motd
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

How can i get this log fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no PAM expert, but that would probably be happening because the `pam_unix` authentication module (local user database: `/etc/password` and `/etc/shadow`) is being consulted before the `pam_winbind` module (Samba/Active Directory).  I am looking at the `auth` lines in your `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`, and assuming that `system-auth` is connected to `password-auth` (which `/etc/pam.d/sshd` references).

When logging in as an AD user, `pam_unix` would not find the user locally, and so PAM would log an authentication failure for that module.  Because `pam_unix` is marked as `sufficient`, not finding the user locally isn't considered a complete failure, and so PAM advances to the next module, eventually reaching `pam_winbind`, which successfully authenticates the AD user.

I don't know of a way to suppress just the log message, but in theory you could change the order of the `auth` module lines so that `pam_unix` is  consulted after `pam_winbind`. Whether that is a good idea or not in practice would need to be evaluated.

Of course, the PAM configuration is very security sensitive, so you should carefully consider and investigate any changes, and test them thoroughly on a non-production system first. For example, what happens if the Samba service is unavailable, and you need to log in as a local user?  How does the `pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000` check fit in?  And so on.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note however that  the way your post is formulated, it looks like troubleshooting suggestions rather than a definitive solution, which is what the answer section is meant for. If that was not intended, please consider editing the answer; otherwise you may want to consider placing a comment below the original question.

Comment: "_you could change the order of the auth module lines so that `pam_unix` is consulted after `pam_winbind`_" - in the event that remote authentication service is unavailable this can potentially lock out local user accounts